# Write two similar methods -one with bang, one without- while respecting DRY concept

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm monkey-patching Array to add my own method `Array#left_outer_join`. Since I'm new to Ruby, I want to do pretty things and have a method that'll return a new array and a bang method that will replace my current one. However, I ended up writing the same code twice with the only difference between non-bang and bang method being a call to map or map! respectively.

I've read a bit on blocks and metaprogramming and ended up with the following:

```
class Array
  def left_outer_join_proc(method, ary, &block)
    self.send(method) do |obj1|
      ary.each do |obj2|
        if yield obj1, obj2
          obj2.keys.each do |key|
            obj1[key] = obj2[key]
          end
          break
        end
      end
      obj1
    end
  end

  def left_outer_join(ary, &block)
    left_outer_join_proc(:map, ary, &block)
  end

  def left_outer_join!(ary, &block)
    left_outer_join_proc(:map!, ary, &block)
  end
end

events.left_outer_join!(users) {|event, user| event['user_id'] == user['user_id'] }
```

So far this works just fine, `Object.send` is (according to SO) the best use to dynamically call a method and I kinda like this approach (though the purist in me loathes polluting the `Array` class with a third method).

The question now: what are the best practices to define both a non-bang and a bang method and keep it DRY?

EDIT: This question is not about "does bang method mean destructive method?" but really about "If I were to write `Array#add_two` and `Array#add_two!`, how could ensure I don't have to define a method with `map{|x| x +2 }` and another with `map!{|x| x + 2 }`.

I know I could use

```
def add_two!(x)
  self = add_two(x)
end
```

but I'm asking for a "best performance, best readability" type of answer (Look at [the sources](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21) for `Array#map` and `Array#map!` to see the 'subtle' performance difference) .

Comment: "best readability" is subjective, of course. I'd choose `self = add_two(x)` over most (all?) alternatives.

Comment: JFYI, you don't need to use double backticks for inline code. Single backticks are enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also factor out the code for a single item, then be a little more verbose in the array methods. The `left_outer_join_element()` method here makes practical sense on its own and is reusable even for non-Array objects.

```
def left_outer_join(ary, &block)
  self.map { |e| left_outer_join_element(e, ary, &block) }
end

def left_outer_join!(ary, &block)
  self.map! { |e| left_outer_join_element(e, ary, &block) }
end

protected

def left_outer_join_element(element, ary, &block)
  ary.each do |obj|
    if yield element, obj
      obj.keys.each do |key|
        element[key] = obj[key]
      end
      break
    end
  end
  element
end
```

Comment: Best answer hands down.

Nothing came out of the "What are the best practices?" so I guess there are none but you managed to refactor my logic function into something that can be used somewhere else by itself and not just be an 'illogic' refactor written just for the sake of avoiding DRY. Kudos :)

Answer (score 1):

> what are the best practices to define both a non-bang and a bang method

There are no such "best practices" that apply to all situations. Use your common sense.

For example, `map!` of array will mutate the array in-place. The bang version means "Danger! Destructive method!". Possible implementation:

```
def map
  # do the mapping
end

def map!
  @elements = map
end
```

`save!` of ActiveRecord will raise error if operation was unsuccessful. Bang means "Will raise error".

In general, exclamation mark in the method names should warn the programmer, "look out, something dangerous can/will happen here". Possible implementation:

```
def save
  save!
  true
rescue
  false
end

def save!
  # do the saving. Raise error if something goes wrong
end
```

Again, there can be zillion of use-cases for bang versions of a method, so there can not be a single pattern/approach.

Comment: Sorry, the part about "non-bang vs bang" was unclear. My question was in term of code base: If I were to write Array#add_two and Array_add_two!, how could ensure I don't have to define a method with "map{|x| x +2 }" and another with "map!{|x| x + 2 }" which would effectively repeating myself.

Comment: In this concrete case a proc would serve. `add2 = proc{|x| x + 2}; map(&add2); map!(&add2)`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the "repetition" here:

```
  def left_outer_join(ary, &block)
    left_outer_join_proc(:map, ary, &block)
  end

  def left_outer_join!(ary, &block)
    left_outer_join_proc(:map!, ary, &block)
  end
```

I would say you have done as much as is reasonable in this case. The `def` and method names are necessary, and so is the call to the proc where you do have most of the shared logic. Although the difference in terms of string edits is low, the placement of the differences is critical. It's also fairly easy to read and understand your code.

To go further you could do something like

```
 ['', '!'].each do |bang_type|
   define_method( "left_outer_join#{bang_type}" ) do |ary, &block|
     left_outer_join_proc( "map#{bang_type}", ary, &block )
   end
 end
```

But the above is taking the DRY concept to extremes where the resulting code is much harder to read and debug.

Answer (score 1):

Some objects (e.g. `Array`s or `String`s) have a method that allows you to replace the entire internal state of the object with the state of another object of the same type. This method is typically aptly named `replace`. For objects which have such a method, you can simply implement the destructive method in terms of `replace` and the non-destructive method:

```
def foo
  # return new instance
end

def foo!
  replace(foo)
  nil # or self
end
```

Conversely, all objects have a method which creates a duplicate copy with identical internal state, called `dup`. You can implement the non-destructive version in terms of `dup` and the destructive version:

```
def foo!
  # modify internal state
  nil # or self
end

def foo
  dup.foo!
end
```

There may be cases, however, where the destructive and non-destructive versions can be made more efficient by implementing them differently. In that case, some duplication probably can't be avoided.

Note that

```
self = add_two(x)
```

doesn't work. It isn't even syntactically valid. And even if it *were* syntactically valid, it would simply assign to a local variable named `self` and not change the special keyword `self`.

Comment: Since internally `replace` is actually a copy, it is the same principle as an assignement copy like in Sergio's implementation (`def map!; @elements = map; end`. Since we are mapping, I am looking for solution that would work straight on my source object.

And sorry about the awful `self = add_two(x)`, I must have gotten confused somewhere in syntaxes.